# Render html element string(with the custom directive on element.) Angular 4.3+ with AOT

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-cli, angular-components, angular-compiler

I have HTML element string coming from the backend with the custom directive on element.

For example:

```
str = "abc xyz <span [customDirective]='2'>qwerty</span> pqrs"
```

**I want to render this as HTML so `customDirective` get in the action.**

I get this working with couple solutions without -aot(just `ng serve`)

But nothing is working with -aot(`ng serve -aot`) or on production build (`ng build -prod`)

#### 1. Using [innerHTML] directive

> Renders HTML string correctly but this cleared out the directive from the element.

#### 2. Dynamically loading the component

[I tried this well-explained solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38888009/5236174)
*This worked without -aot*

But when I ran with -aot (or at production build) got this error:

> "No NgModulele metadata found for RuntimeComponentModule"

#### 3. Dynamically loading the component differently

[I tried this another solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42065289/5236174) *This also worked without -aot*

But when I ran with -aot (or at production build) got this error:

> Runtime compiler is not loaded

#### 4. Tried solving the error in #3

To solve that I loaded the compiler this way and used that to create a component.

```
const compilerFactory: CompilerFactory =
            platformBrowserDynamic().injector.get(CompilerFactory);
this.compiler = compilerFactory.createCompiler([]);
```

*This also worked without -aot*

Got this error when ran with -aot (or at production build):

> A platform with a different configuration has been created. Please destroy it first.

**Anyone ran into the similar issue please help here.**

I have also gone through the [Dynamic Component Loader](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader)
but that only pass the data dynamically to the already defined components.

Here I am looking to create component dynamically with the dynamic template for that which the string I am getting from the backend.

Comment: On Same boat, I have tried almost everything available as articles. No solution for generating components from HTML strings.